# Динамическая подгрузка селектов

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Есть 4 селекта (с айди #model, #color, #size, #amortizator), от значения 1 селекта зависят последние 3. Выбрав значение в верхнем селекте должны загрузиться доступные значения в нижних 3.

Это у меня сделано так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#model").change(function(){
        var ramavalue = $("#model option:selected").val();
        //alert(ramavalue);
        $("#color").load('/const/api.php?ramaid='+ ramavalue +'&color=y');
        $("#size").load('/const/api.php?ramaid='+ ramavalue +'&size=y');
        $("#amortizator").load('/const/api.php?ramaid='+ ramavalue +'&amortizator=y');
        var amzid = $("#amortizator option:selected").val();
        $(".amortizatordesc").load('/const/api.php?amzid='+ amzid +'&amortizatordesc=y');
    });
    $("#amortizator").change(function(){
        var amzid = $("#amortizator option:selected").val();
        $(".amortizatordesc").load('/const/api.php?amzid='+ amzid +'&amortizatordesc=y');
    });
});
```

верхний селектор имеет #model, значения остальных 3 нормально загружаются при выборе/изменени option в верхнем.

Проблема в дополнительном поле. В тег `<p></p>` с классом .amortizatordesc должно загружаться описание значения из 4 селекта с айди #amortizator.
Но при открытии страницы изначально в теге пусто. При смене же значения в 1 селекторе в тег загружается описание прошлого селекта. То есть идет отставание.

При смене значения вручную в 4 селекте #amortizator, все нормально. А при изменени верхнего значения селекта #model показывает описание предыдущего выбранного селекта.

Не совсем ясно написал, но надеюсь кто нибудь поймет какая у меня проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто вызывайте в конце функции $('#model').change событие изменения для последнего селекта:

```
$("#model").change(function(){
    // ... Ваш предыдущий код
    $("#amortizator").trigger('change');
});
```

[Пример](http://jsbin.com/ijoxew/1/).

Comment: что-то не выходит у меня, без изменений

Comment: Я поторопился, не учел что у вас подгрузка с сервера. Вам нужно добавить trigger('change') в callback последнего .load(), который изменяет нужный селект: проще говоря, вы должны делать trigger ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ТОГО, как получили данные с сервера и вставили их в этот селект.

Comment: $(".amortizatordesc").load('/const/api.php?amzid='+ amzid + $('#amortizator').trigger('change') + '&amortizatordesc=y');

Comment: Что то типо такого? Все равно не выходит пока.

Comment: Нет, читайте документацию по load.

    $(".amortizatordesc").load('/const/api.php?amzid='+ amzid +'&amortizatordesc=y', function(){ $('#amortizator').trigger('change') });

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!